# Index View donot show 'Contains' operator for (exposed) filter

Tags: views, search

I have created an indexed view, for facet search.
Now I want to put a text field from which search provides a result, that contains that string from the title.

[image]

Now, title here donot have operator, 'Contains' which is required to filter matching titles.

[image]

I am using Global Populate filter as exposed filter.
I tried using hook_views_query_alter which donot work with index view of search api.
How should we do this?

Answer (score 1):

I used hook_search_api_views_query_alter from search_api_views.api.php.

```
function MYMODULE_search_api_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // Altering the title filter to operator LIKE which is not available in the 
  // views itself.
  if ($view->name = '[VIEWNAME]') {
    if (!empty($query->where[1]['conditions'][0][1])) {
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][0][1] = '%' . $query->where[1]['conditions'][0][1] . '%';
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][0][2] = 'LIKE';
    }
  }
}
```